# mui-tree-select set value selected by default

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to set default value to this package "mui-tree-select" But I cant do it please some help me out this.

with this sandbox code https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mikepricedev/mui-tree-select

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass selected array of id selected item as a props to TreeView  component

```
  <TreeView  selected={selected} >.....
```

this link could help you :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/react-mui-treeview-api/

Answer (score 0):

You can set `defaultSelected` to default selected `nodeId` property.

```
 const defaultSelectedNodeId = 0;
 
 <TreeView defaultSelected={defaultSelectedNodeId}>
  <TreeItem nodeId="0" label={lable}></TreeItem>
 </TreeView>
```